# fastapi-crudrouter: how to pass url parameter to dependency?

Tags: dependency-injection, fastapi, fastapi-crudrouter

While I am using [fastapi-crudrouter](https://fastapi-crudrouter.awtkns.com/) am trying to have a resource be accessed only by its owner.

Somehow I am getting the error

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "query",
        "id"
      ],
      "msg": "field required",
      "type": "value_error.missing"
    }
  ]
}
```

The code is pasted below. I think the error is complaining about the missing `id` parameter. The endpoint url goes like `.../support/issue/1`. How can I make that 1 assigned to the `id` parameter of the `user_is_owner` dependency?

```
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from fastapi_crudrouter import SQLAlchemyCRUDRouter

from app.support.models import Issue as IssueModel
from app.support.schemas import Issue as IssueSchema
from app.database import get_db
from app.oauth2 import get_current_user


def user_is_owner(
    id: int,
    db: Session = Depends(get_db),
    current_user: int = Depends(get_current_user),
):
    issue = db.query(IssueModel).filter(IssueModel.id == id).first()
    if not issue:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail=f'Issue with id: {id} was not found.',
        )

    if issue.created_by != current_user.id:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
            detail='Not authorized to perform requested action',
        )
    return True


router = SQLAlchemyCRUDRouter(
    schema=IssueSchema,
    # create_schema=PotatoCreate,
    # update_schema=PotatoUpdate,
    db_model=IssueModel,
    db=get_db,
    prefix='/issue',
    dependencies=[Depends(get_current_user)],
    #
    # individual route config
    #
    get_all_route=True,  # [Depends(is_admin)],
    get_one_route=[Depends(user_is_owner)],
    delete_all_route=False,
    delete_one_route=False,
    # create_route=False,
    update_route=False,
)
```

Comment: Show us how your endpoint is declared.

Comment: @fchancel: I am using a library called fastapi-crudrouter (https://fastapi-crudrouter.awtkns.com/) here. The endpoints are defined by it.

Comment: @Chris: that would override the whole get_one_route. My question is about using the default get_one_route if the user mets some condition.